# What's an elegant way to parse this data format in Clojure?

Tags: parsing, clojure

[A legacy application I work with](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpublic.support.unisys.com%2F2200%2Fdocs%2Fcp13.1%2Fpdf%2F78311784-006.pdf&ei=YXKxUo6OKISp4gSK9YDQDw&usg=AFQjCNHFsHmRBVzwYd_QvzmmJpDcizZVVQ&sig2=IMNWMkKCttyH_8k9trlSng&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE) has a funky data format called SGS. I've considered and started on a number of brute-force solutions including a hand-generated finite state machine and a custom recursive descent parser, but I'm striving to build an application where the amount of (non-library) source code is just enough to express what needs to be done.

So I've been looking at Clojure-based parsers. I've fiddled with

- [Clearley](https://github.com/mthvedt/clearley),
- [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse),
- [Parse-EZ](https://github.com/protoflex/parse-ez), and
- [Squarepeg](https://github.com/ericnormand/squarepeg).

None of these have enough documentation/support on the 'net to get me off to a running start. So I'm looking for someone with experience with one of these tools (or a good alternative) to give me a hand.

Here's the data language:

---

- Data is represented by rows having a label (starting in col. 1) and 1 or more fields, separated by one or more spaces.
- Fields consist of one or more subfields, separated by commas. Commas may be *followed* by spaces for legibility but these aren't significant.
- Labels are identifiers consisting of characters in the set [-$0-9A-Z_*%] and need not be unique.
- Subfields are either identifiers or quoted strings or missing (nil). Quoted strings are delimited by *2* leading single quotes and *2* trailing single quotes. Quoted strings don't contain single quotes, so there's no quote nesting or escaping to worry about.
- Space-dot-space starts a rest-of-line comment. Space-dot at the end of a line is an empty rest-of-line comment. Dot-space at the beginning of a line makes the entire line a comment. A line consisting of only a dot is also a line comment.
- Rows may be continued across two or more lines. A semicolon as the last non-blank, non-comment character on a line means the row is continued on the next line as if both the semicolon and line break were nonexistent.
- Semicolons and dots (with or without spaces) have no special significance inside comments or quoted strings.

**Example**:

```
. Comment
.
LAB1  F1S1                       . Minimal data row, with line comment
LAB1  F1S1,F1S2,F1S3  F2S1  F3S1 . 2nd row with same label
LAB2  , , , F1S4     ''Field #2 (only 1 subfield)''  F3S1,,F3S3
LAB99 F1S1,                      . Field 1 has 2 subfields, 2nd is nil
LAB3  F1S1,F1S2, ;
      F1S3       ;
      F2S1                       . Row continued over 3 lines.
```

---

Hand-parsing my example, I would like a result like this:

```
[
 ("LAB1" ["F1S1"])
 ("LAB1" ["F1S1" "F1S2" "F1S3"] ["F2S1"] ["F3S1"])
 ("LAB2" [nil nil nil "F1S4"] ["Field #2 (only 1 subfield"] ["F3S1" nil "F3S3"])
 ("LAB99" ["F1S1" nil])
 ("LAB3" ["F1S1" "F1S2" "F1S3"] ["F2S1"])
]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

@edwood suggested showing an implementation of my own for people to use as a starting point. I had hesitated to do that to avoid pre-biasing people in a particular direction, but with the dearth of responses this may be "better than nothing."

Here, then, is my own InstaParse solution, which sorta-works:

```
     SGS = (<COMMENT_LINE> / DATA_LINES) *
     COMMENT_LINE = #' *\\.(?: [^\\n]*)?\\n' 
     DATA_LINES = LABEL FIELDS SEPARATOR? (LINE_COMMENT | '\\n')
     LABEL = IDENTIFIER
     FIELDS = '' | (SEPARATOR FIELD)+
     SEPARATOR = CONTINUATION #' +' | #' +' (CONTINUATION #' *')?
     CONTINUATION = #'; *\\n'
     LINE_COMMENT = #' .[^\\n]*\\n'  
     FIELD = SUBFIELD (',' SEPARATOR? SUBFIELD)*
     SUBFIELD = IDENTIFIER | QUOTED_STRING | ''
     IDENTIFIER = #'[-$0-9A-Z_*%]+'
     QUOTED_STRING = #'\\'\\'[^\\']*\\'\\''
```

While debugging, it managed to process 249 lines before hitting an error I needed to debug. But once I fixed that, and it presumably went to work on my whole 431 lines of data, and ended up choking, after about 2 minutes, with

> CompilerException java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space,
>   compiling:(sgs2.clj:40:13)

I moved the easily regexp-handled stuff to regexps, and this seems to have helped performance. Comment lines, for example, are now trivial to parse because they directly match a single regexp, or not.

---

If I chop my input data down to 228 lines, the parser runs and produces a correct result in 16 seconds. I think this is a very long time for a very small amount of data. Am I doing something dramatically wrong?

Comment: One clojure parser I have heard a lot about is parsley - https://github.com/cgrand/parsley . But I never tried it before.

Comment: instaparse has a good readme/docs. Try that first.

Comment: @edbond: I tried Instaparse and was happy to quickly create a parser that worked well on small data sets. However, inexplicably, my parser exploded (i.e. stalled and then produced exceptions) on a file of just a few hundred lines.

Comment: maybe you should add a parser and example files and someone helps

Comment: For others who arrive here later: Parsley is a LR(0) parser generator, which is good for parsing things like S-expressions, which have clear, unambiguous beginning and end markers. For anything else, you will tear your hair out trying to get a Parsley parser to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is instaparse parser I end up with:

```
"<SGS> = (<COMMENT_ROW> | ROW)+
<NL> = '\\n'
<qq> = \"''\"
space = <#'\\s*'>
COMMENT_ROW = COMMENT NL?
LABEL = 'LAB' #'\\d+'
EMPTY_F = <space>
FFIELD = 'F' #'[0-9A-Z]+'
QFIELD = (<qq> (!qq #'.')+ <qq>)
<F> = FFIELD / QFIELD / EMPTY_F
F_SEP = ((space? | ',')* ';' NL space?) / (<space?> ',' <space?>) / <space>
<NEXT_FIELDS> = F <space?> (<F_SEP> NEXT_FIELDS)? <space?>
FIELDS = F <space?> (<F_SEP> NEXT_FIELDS)? <space?>
COMMENT = '.' #'.*'
ROW = LABEL <space?> FIELDS <space?> <COMMENT?> <NL?>"
```

I hope someone can improve or simplify that.
Result of parsing example input:

```
sgs.core> (sgs example-input)
([:ROW [:LABEL "LAB" "1"] [:FIELDS [:FFIELD "F" "1S1"]]] [:ROW [:LABEL "LAB" "1"] [:FIELDS [:FFIELD "F" "1S1"] [:FFIELD "F" "1S2"] [:FFIELD "F" "1S3"] [:FFIELD "F" "2S1"] [:FFIELD "F" "3S1"]]] [:ROW [:LABEL "LAB" "2"] [:FIELDS [:EMPTY_F] [:EMPTY_F] [:EMPTY_F] [:FFIELD "F" "1S4"] [:QFIELD "F" "i" "e" "l" "d" " " "#" "2" " " "(" "o" "n" "l" "y" " " "1" " " "s" "u" "b" "f" "i" "e" "l" "d" ")"] [:FFIELD "F" "3S1"] [:EMPTY_F] [:FFIELD "F" "3S3"]]] [:ROW [:LABEL "LAB" "99"] [:FIELDS [:FFIELD "F" "1S1"] [:EMPTY_F]]] [:ROW [:LABEL "LAB" "3"] [:FIELDS [:FFIELD "F" "1S1"] [:FFIELD "F" "1S2"] [:FFIELD "F" "1S3"] [:FFIELD "F" "2S1"]]])
```

It takes about 50 msec on my machine.
I have added couple functions to cleanup results.

```
sgs.core> (pprint (parse-and-transform sgs example-input))
[("LAB1" ["F1S1"])
 ("LAB1" ["F1S1" "F1S2" "F1S3"] ["F2S1"] ["F3S1"])
 ("LAB2"
  [nil nil nil "F1S4"]
  ["Field #2 (only 1 subfield)"]
  ["F3S1" nil "F3S3"])
 ("LAB99" ["F1S1" nil])
 ("LAB3" ["F1S1" "F1S2" "F1S3"] ["F2S1"])]
```

Full source code here: https://gist.github.com/edbond/8052305

On performance you can read https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse/blob/master/docs/Performance.md

I would try to partition large input into small chunks.

Comment: Hey @edbond, thank you *very* much for your work on this! Thanks to your use of parametrization, your code is very clean and legible. I think you misunderstood my spec re subfields; they all start with "F" in my simple example but in real life they can be any of the allowed chars. Anyway, I took your advice and built my own Instaparse scanner, please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get what you want using Parse-EZ. Note that I turned off the default
whitespace/comments functionality of Parse-EZ (with-trim-off).  The entry function is "sgs" at the bottom of the listing.  You can invoke the parser as: ***(parse sgs your-input-string)***

```
(ns sgs-parser
  (:use [protoflex.parse]))

(defn line-comments [] (multi* #(regex #"(\r?\n)?\..*\r?\n")))
(defn wsp [] (regex #"[ \t]*(\. .*)?"))
(defn trim [parse-fn] (wsp) (let [r (parse-fn)]  (wsp) r))

(defn label [] (regex #"[-$0-9A-Z_*%]+"))
(defn quoted-str [] (between #(string "''") #(regex #"[^']*") #(string "''")))

(defn sub-field [] (trim #(any label quoted-str)))

(defn- eol? [] (starts-with-re? #"\r?\n"))
(defn field [] 
  (when (not (or (eol?) (at-end?)))
    (when (starts-with? ";") (skip-over "\n"))
    (loop [sfs []]
      (let [sf (opt sub-field)]
        (if (opt #(trim comma))
          (recur (conj sfs sf))
          (conj sfs sf))))))

(defn record [] 
  (line-comments) 
  (let [ret (into [(trim label)] (multi+ field))]
    (any #(regex #"\r?\n") at-end?)
    ret))

(defn sgs [] (with-trim-off (wsp) (multi* record)))
```

Comment: Wow, this is marvellously concise, thank you! I'm getting an error on a line of my input that contains a label and a comment but no fields. Now I'll have to try to figure out how your magic works.

Comment: The code above expects atleast one field after label, as it uses "multi+". If zero fields is valid input, use "multi*" instead of "multi+".

Comment: Eep, I've neglected that project for a bit. Thanks for the suggestion!!